# Wrong Content-Type header set automatically in Axios call

Tags: axios, http-headers

A bug was reported by a user of an app that I manage (the backend is written in Java with SB2, frontend in Typescript with React): a HTTP request to upload a file via a multipart form has a `Content-Type: application/json` header before the multipart one, which leads to a 400 error. The call is triggered in the UI and sent by an internal Axios call.

This user is the only one to experience this problem, and only on some instances of the app. I cannot reproduce it on my end, and so far I have eliminated these possible causes:

- browser or browser version
- instance-specific configuration
- server host (we use GCP and AWS but it happens with both)

I'd like to know if something (configuration, software, plugin) on the user's side could cause this, despite them not sending the request directly. If you have ever experienced this problem, any knowledge about it is welcomed.